# create an arbitrary intance of "type"

Tags: haskell, testing, functional-programming, functional-testing, quickcheck

I have the following,

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)
```

I want to generate random values of this type with some restrictions (both has to be 0-8)

I would like to do something like

```
instance Arbitrary Pos where
  arbitrary = do x <- choose(0,8) 
                 y <- choose(0,8)
                 return (x,y)
```

and then use it in my test to have valid positions.

This won't work bc I'm aliasing(?) tuples

other methods I have tried are to use implications in my test to say

```
prop_my_prop (x,y) = abs x < 9  && abs y < 9 ==> ...
```

but I think that's pretty ugly and in theory it might exhaust the quickchecktest (run over 1000 times).

this is an assignment so I just want some indication were to look or how to approach this, I'm not allowed to change Pos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don Stewart's answer describes the arguably best way to do it. However, if for some reason you don't want to use a newtype you can use a custom generator as follows:

```
positionsToTest :: Gen Pos
positionsToTest = do x <- choose (0,8)
                     y <- choose (0,8)
                     return (x,y)

prop_myTest = forAll positionsToTest ( \ pos -> myProperty pos )
```

Runnung quickCheck on prop_myTest should do what you want.

Answer (score 6):

> This won't work bc I'm aliasing(?) tuples

Yes, that's correct. Define a new data type and you can have a new instance.

```
data Pos = Pos Int Int
```

or

```
newtype Pos = Pos (Int, Int)
```

Then you can write your own Arbitrary instance with whatever generator you like.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the type Pos to data Pos

Comment: Then you must write your generator as a function rather than a method of type class.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you can't change `Pos` to a `data` or `newtype` for whatever reason, you could always do the following: define a wrapper

```
newtype PosA = PosA { unPosA :: Pos } deriving (Eq,Show) -- and whatever else you need!
```

along with an `Arbitrary` instance for it:

```
instance Arbitrary PosA where
  arbitrary = do x <- choose(0,8) 
                 y <- choose(0,8)
                 return $ PosA (x,y)
```

and finally, rewrite all the propositions you want to check so that their type no longer mentions `Pos` but only `PosA` instead. Say for example that you had a function `mirror` and the property that mirroring twice is the identity:

```
mirror :: Pos -> Pos
mirror (x,y) = (y,x)

prop_mirror :: Pos -> Bool
prop_mirror pos = mirror (mirror pos) == pos
```

Then you'd need to make `prop_mirror_A`, something like this (untested code!)

```
prop_mirror_A :: PosA -> Bool
prop_mirror_A pos = prop_mirror (unPosA pos)
```

and you're off to the races. You can probably do some of the work 'lifting' from `prop_mirror` to `prop_mirror_A` by Clever Typeclass Wizardry, but I'm not going to think about that now :-)

(Incidentally, this is a good reason why type synonyms are usually not the right choice!)